# How can i check if a mail has a valid digital signature - VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, mapi

I have a function that find a specific mail with subject, i also want to add some methods to find out if the mail has a valid digital signature.

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set myNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")   
Set ClientFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(6) 'Inbox = 6 
Set myItems = ClientFolder.Items 
Set myItem = myItems.GetFirst 
Set colSyc = myNameSpace.SyncObjects
Set syc = colSyc.AppFolders
ClientFolder.InAppFolderSyncObject = True 
syc.Start 'Sync inbox at most updated state

For intMailCount = 0 to ClientFolder.Items.Count - 1 ' Check subject line for a match       
    If Instr(myItem.Subject, Subject) = 1 AND myItem.Unread = True then             
        VerifyEmailSubject = "True" 

    'validation under here does not work properly and allways returns true and need to find something here for validation
    If myItem.MessageClass <> "IPM.Note.SMIME" Or myItem.MessageClass <> "IPM.Note.Secure" Or myItem.MessageClass <> "IPM.Note.Secure.Sign" then
        msgbox "signed"
    End If
        myItem.Unread = false   'Set mail status to read to avoid further test assertion errors.    
    Exit For        
End If 
    Set myItem = myItems.GetNext 
Next
```

Comment: Solved >>  
 If myItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note.SMIME.MultipartSigned" Then       
  VerifyEmailSignature = "True"    
 End If

Comment: Consider taking this off the unanswered questions list by posting an answer then accepting it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
If myItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note.SMIME.MultipartSigned" Then 
    VerifyEmailSignature = "True"   
End If
```